# Signing identity not found on XCODE (Organizer)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile, organizer

I already made iPhone application thanks to all certificates and so on.
Now, I'm installing a second mac to develop applicaions (the same applications) so :

- I generated a Certification Signin Request (with keychain)
- I didn't upload it but I downloaded the Distribution Certificate (that I generated before with the old computer), and install it (in keychain again)
- I Downloaded the Distribution Provisioning profile

The last File , I installed it and in Organizer, the status of the file is "Valid Signing identity not found".

How can I fix that problem ?

This is common operations but I always have trouble with all those certificates :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Export your existing certificate from your old machine to your new one. This will make you skip all other stuff to do and it's easy as 1,2,3.

Comment: Go to Keychain Access on your old machine. find the certificate, right click and export. then copy the exported file into your new machine, then just doubleclick it.

Comment: I've exported the "iPhone Distribution: xxx", and imported it but I have a "There are no valid certificate/private key pairs in the default keychain" . When I check keychain, the certificate is on the new mac !

Comment: Dude, I forgot, you have to export the key as well, the key that is paired with the certificate

Comment: Ok thanks. Now I've one Apple Application Integration Autority, an Apple Code signin Certification Autority, an Apple Worldwide Developper Relations Certification Autority, an iPhone Distribution: xx  but it gave me the same error. Wich is the name of the paired certificate ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Ok, step by step: Open Keychain Access on old mac. Select "login" in your Keychains menu. Select "Certificates" in your Category menu. Find your certificate (it should have a gray triangle at the left of the certificate name). Click the triangle, and you should see the key. Right click on the key to export. Copy exported file to your new mac. double click the file. Tada!!

Comment: Thanks, I understand.. But " A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.xx.yy" could not be found"

Comment: I could help you faster under a Teamviewer session. Find me on skype id: diabolator2

Comment: This is the certificates in my old : http://www.imagup.com/data/1157290638.html and those pictures are in the new computer : http://www.imagup.com/data/1157291075.html and http://www.imagup.com/data/1157291099.html

Comment: @Terodor : Thanks ! I added you 5min ago ;-)